# Attempting an RPN function in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, each

I'm creating a RPN calculator in ruby, however when I believe my each statement is incorrect and I do not know if my calculation is correct following it in the loop. I'm pretty new to ruby so any input on what could be done to fix this code I would greatly appreciate it. To be specific my questions primarily are

- How would I properly iterate an input given the input is "11+" and go digit by digit. I don't believe that my current code is doing that and despite trail and error I can't seem to find a a solution.
- Where would modulo be in order of operations?
  I've yet to do this part as I still am puzzled on why my string is not being evaluated for integer then stacked.

  ```
  def calc(input)
  token=input.split
  stack=[]
  input.each do |token|
  if input.each == Integer # if the item is a number put it in the stack#
     stack << token # push the value into the stack array#
  else # when the item is an operator run the following calculation#
  case input
  when "+"
  stack.push(stack.pop + stack.pop)
  when "-"
  stack.push(stack.pop - stack.pop)
  when "x"
  stack.push(stack.pop * stack.pop)
  when "/"
  stack.push (stack.pop / stack.pop)
  when "%"
  stack.push (stack.pop % stack.pop)
  end 
  end 
  end
  end
  ```

Comment: What do you mean by "Where would modulo be in order of operations?" The whole *point* of RPN is that *there is no such thing as order of operations*, it is simply evaluated left-to-right.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `input` is a string. You could simplify the method using [Object#public_send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-public_send).

```
def calc(str)
  stack = []
  str.split.each do |token|
    if token.match?(/\A-?\d+\z/)
      stack << token.to_i
    else
      rec = stack.shift
      arg = stack.shift
      stack << rec.public_send(token, arg)
    end
  end
  stack
end            

str = "2 3 + 6 * 5 / 2 -"
calc(str)
  #=> [4]
```

The regular expression reads, "match the beginning of the string (`\A`), optionally followed by a minus sign (`-?`), followed by one or more digits (`\d+`), followed by the end of the string (`\z`)".

You can add some `puts` statements to follow the calculations.

```
def calc(str)
  stack = []
  str.split.each do |token|
    puts "stack=#{stack}, token=#{token}"
    puts "  an integer?=#{token.match?(/\A-?\d+\z/)}"
    if token.match?(/\A-?\d+\z/)
      stack << token.to_i
      puts "  stack after stack << token.to_i=#{stack}" 
    else
      rec = stack.shift
      arg = stack.shift
      puts "  rec=#{rec}, arg=#{arg}, stack=#{stack}"
      stack << rec.public_send(token, arg)
      puts "  stack after stack<<#{rec}.public_send(#{token},#{arg})=#{stack}"
    end
  end
  stack
end            
  #=> [4]
```

and prints the following.

```
stack=[], token=2
  an integer?=true
  stack after stack << token.to_i=[2]
stack=[2], token=3
  an integer?=true
  stack after stack << token.to_i=[2, 3]
stack=[2, 3], token=+
  an integer?=false
  rec=2, arg=3, stack=[]
  stack after stack << 2.public_send(+, 3)=[5]
stack=[5], token=6
  an integer?=true
  stack after stack << token.to_i=[5, 6]
stack=[5, 6], token=*
  an integer?=false
  rec=5, arg=6, stack=[]
  stack after stack << 5.public_send(*, 6)=[30]
stack=[30], token=5
  an integer?=true
  stack after stack << token.to_i=[30, 5]
stack=[30, 5], token=/
  an integer?=false
  rec=30, arg=5, stack=[]
  stack after stack << 30.public_send(/, 5)=[6]
stack=[6], token=2
  an integer?=true
  stack after stack << token.to_i=[6, 2]
stack=[6, 2], token=-
  an integer?=false
  rec=6, arg=2, stack=[]
  stack after stack << 6.public_send(-, 2)=[4]
```